# MaterialUI-Next Close drawer on children click

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am running MaterialUI-Next and I've tried all variants of the drawer but I can't get it to close when an item in the drawer has been clicked. I know the temporary variant allows me to do that but it closes when anything is clicked. I need it to close only when a ListItem is clicked.

In my case, I have a ExpansionPanel in the drawer with Lists and ListItems in it. Clicking the ExpansionPanel shouldn't close the drawer, the drawer should remain open because I am not ready to navigate away. However when I click a ListItem in the drawer (They contain `component="a"` items) then the drawer should close and the component="a" navigated to its href.

My code is extremely basic and vanilla, practically the exact demo from [MaterialUI-Next Drawers](https://material-ui-next.com/demos/drawers/). They also have a playground to test code. But anyhow, here is some of my relevant code

**My drawer:**

```
<Drawer
    variant="persistent" //I tried "temporary", and "permanent" as well
    elevation={16}
    anchor="right"
    open={this.state.open}
    // onClick={(open) => this.setState({ open: false })}
    // onKeyDown={(open) => this.setState({ open: false })}>
    <SystemMenu />
</Drawer>
```

**My Content stored in SystemMenu:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { withStyles } from 'material-ui-next/styles';
import List, { ListItem, ListItemText } from 'material-ui-next/List';
import ExpansionPanel, { ExpansionPanelDetails, ExpansionPanelSummary } from 'material-ui-next/ExpansionPanel';
import ListSubheader from 'material-ui-next/List/ListSubheader';
import {ChevronDown} from 'mdi-material-ui';
import Grid from 'material-ui-next/Grid';
const OTHERPAGES = require('data/pages.js');
const systemMenuData = OTHERPAGES['systemMenuPagesItems'];

class SystemMenu extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            expanded: null,
        };
    }

    handleChange = panel => (event, expanded) => {
        this.setState({
            open: false,
            expanded: expanded ? panel : false,
        });
    };

    render() {
        const { expanded, open } = this.state;
        return (
            <div>
                <Grid
                    container>
                    <Grid item xs={12} style={{padding: 0}}>
                        <ListSubheader component="div">MENU ITEMS</ListSubheader>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
                <Grid
                    container>
                    <Grid item xs={12}>
                        <ExpansionPanel
                            expanded={expanded === 'panel1'}
                            onChange={this.handleChange('panel1')}>
                            <ExpansionPanelSummary
                                expandIcon={<ChevronDown />}>
                                Players
                            </ExpansionPanelSummary>
                            <ExpansionPanelDetails>
                                <List>
                                    <ListItem
                                        button
                                        component="a"
                                        href="/app/page1">
                                        <ListItemText primary="Page 1" />
                                    </ListItem>
                                    <ListItem
                                        button
                                        component="a"
                                        href="/app/page2">                                          
                                        <ListItemText primary="Page 2" />
                                    </ListItem>
                                    <ListItem
                                        button
                                        component="a"
                                        href="/app/page3">                                          
                                        <ListItemText primary="Page 3" />
                                    </ListItem>
                                </List>
                            </ExpansionPanelDetails>
                        </ExpansionPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(SystemMenu);
```

I read in other posts that you can pass the `onKeyDown={(open) => this.setState({ open: false })}` to its children with props. But I am new in React and having some problems with this concept.

Basically, I need to make the onKeyDown work for the ListItems, not the actual drawer. I may or may not have to change my Drawer variant back to temporary for the onKeyDown property to work. Not too sure.

(Remember the link above offers a playground to test code. Much better than me trying to build a jFiddle for React)

**EDIT**

I worked out a different way but not my favorite.

By moving the content in the SystemMenu to the Menu.js file (where my Drawer imports, functions, and states live) I was able to create a handleClose function with timeout so that it closes. This is the function:

```
handleClose = () => {
    if (!this.state.open) {
        return;
    }
    this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({ open: false });
        this.setState({ expanded: null });
    });
};
```

This requires the persistent variant and a `handleOpen()` function to keep the drawer open until I click a List that has the `handleClose()` function. So, my Drawer looks like this now

```
<Drawer
    variant="persistent"
    elevation={16}
    anchor="right"
    open={this.state.open}
    onClick={() => { this.handleOpen(); }}>
    ...
       My System Menu code in here, not too happy about this part. :(
    ...
</Drawer>
```

Next, in my System Menu code that contains the Expansion Panels and Lists, I added the `handleClose()` function to the List and it navigates as well as closing the drawer and expansion panels. Like this:

```
<List 
    className="quickpanel-navigation"
    onClick={() => { this.handleClose(); }}>
    .... ListItems code here ....
</List>
```

This is an Ok method, but I would much rather I had the SystemMenu code in another file and imported to this file and using props to manipulate the closing functions in the Menu.js file from the SystemMenu.js file. If anyone else wants to keep helping me I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the [demo](https://material-ui-next.com/demos/drawers/#temporary-drawer), they're wrapping all of the ListItems in a div that handles closing the drawer:

```js
<div
  tabIndex={0}
  role="button"
  onClick={this.toggleDrawer('left', false)}
  onKeyDown={this.toggleDrawer('left', false)}
>
  {sideList}
</div>
```

In this code, `toggleDrawer` is a function that sets the state used for the Drawer's `open` prop.  So when a key is pressed or a click occurs in one of the List's children, the event bubbles up to these handlers (as long as `event.stopPropagation()` is not used) and state is changed.

In your code, you don't want the expander's click to close the drawer, so you have to handle these events differently.

You can add an `onClick` handler to the List:

```js
<ExpansionPanelDetails>
    <List onClick={ () => { /* close the drawer here */ } }>
        <ListItem
            button
            component="a"
            href="/app/page1">
            <ListItemText primary="Page 1" />
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem
            button
            component="a"
            href="/app/page2">                                          
            <ListItemText primary="Page 2" />
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem
            button
            component="a"
            href="/app/page3">                                          
            <ListItemText primary="Page 3" />
        </ListItem>
    </List>
</ExpansionPanelDetails>
```

Then, when the ListItems are clicked, the event will bubble to the List's handler, which sets state, closing the Drawer.

Based on the structure of your code, you may need to modify your implementation of Drawer to pass a function to your `SystemMenu` component so that the click handler on its List can set the state of its parent because `this.setState` affects the state of `this`, which is the current instance of that component.  It would not set the state of the Drawer.

**UPDATE:**

Based on your comments, I'm adding this bit.

In your SystemMenu component:
 - accept a prop called `closeDrawer`.
 - use this function, from props, as the `onClick` handler on List

- In your Menu component:
- add a function to close the Drawer, let's call it `closeDrawer` for now.
- when rendering SystemMenu, pass `this.closeDrawer` as `closeDrawer

```js
     <SystemMenu closeDrawer={this.closeDrawer} ...>
```

This is one way to alter the local state of Menu, the parent component, from within SystemMenu, the child.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention the SystemMenu is in a separate file I am importing into the file that contains the Drawer. It doesn't recognize the ToggleDrawer function because it is declared in a separate file.

Comment: As well as the Drawer component which it's also not declared in SystemMenu file, but it the Menu.js that contains the Drawer. That's why I thought props would be the right approach. Isn't that what props is supposed to do? To manipulate functions that exist out side of the file? In its parent?

Comment: I figured out a way to get it to work but I have to have the SystemMenu code in the Menu file so I can access the imports and functions. See my EDIT. +1 for your work since you got my gears turning. However, my question remains. I would rather be able to manipulate the drawer from its children code in another file

Comment: I understand that they're in separate files, which is why I wrote that you'll need to pass a function to SystemMenu from where ever your Drawer is defined.  Create a `closeDrawer` function in the class that renders your Drawer and expose a prop in the SystemMenu component that can accept it.  Then in the SystemMenu component, use it as your List's click handler.

Comment: @LOTUSMS see the updated answer where I spell it out.

Answer (score 4):

Place the close handler on the MuiPaper via `PaperProps`:

```
const handleClose = () => console.log('closing drawer');

const MyDrawer = () => <Drawer PaperProps={{onClick: handleClose}} />
```

This will close the drawer when clicked anywhere inside the drawer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Drawer is in a class component, you would do something like this to close it from a child component.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            open: false,
        }
    }

    closeDrawer = () => this.setState({ open: false })

    render() {            
        return (
            <Drawer
                elevation={16}
                anchor="right"
                open={this.state.open}
                onKeyDown={this.closeDrawer}
            >
                <SystemMenu 
                    closeDrawer={this.closeDrawer}
                />
            </Drawer>
        )
    }
}
```

Then you can access `this.props.closeDrawer` from within `SystemMenu`. It sounds like you want to add to the `onClick` handler for your list items:

```
<ListItem
    button
    component="a"
    href="/app/page1"
    onClick={this.props.closeDrawer}
>
    <ListItemText primary="Page 1" />
</ListItem>
```